# Find Cost of join algorithms Block-nested , Index-nested, and Sort Merge

Tags: sql, database, transactions, query-optimization, computer-science

The query is: `Select count(*) From Student s, Registration r Where s.sno = r.sno`.

We are given the following information about the relations:

```
 - Student relation consists of 300 pages with 100 tuples per page.
 - Registration relation contains 900 pages with 100 tuples per page.
 - Course relation contains 300 pages with 100 tuples per page.
 - There exists a B+ tree on Registration<sno> with height 3.
 - 50 buffer pages are available.
```

I need to find the cost of performing the above join using the following algorithms:

```
 - Block-nested loops join
 - Index-nested loops join
 - Sort Merge join
```

I've got the following answer by doing this but don't know whether if it is correct.

```
Block nested
300 (Student Pages) x 900 (Registration Pages) = 270,000 I/O Operations.

Index-nested
300 (Student Pages) x 3 (Index height) = 900 I/O Operations.

Sort Merge
300 (Student pages) + 900 (Registration pages) = 1,200 I/O Operations.
```

Any help is appreciated.